# Classes - how to print values from classes

Tags: python-3.x, class

How to print B pro the following class? I tried it wrong (end of the code). How to correct the last command to save values in B, please?

```
class Field():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.Bx, self.By, self.Bz = kwargs.get('B')
        self.x_, self.y_, self.z_ = kwargs.get('D')

    def atPoint(self, t = 0, x=[-0.010471208152871149, -1.0000565525366247, 0.38080220765137873]): # Initial conditions are copied from result below (x_start)
        # Interpolate
        x_, y_, z_ = self.x_, self.y_, self.z_
        B1 = self.my_3d_interp(x_, y_, z_, self.Bx, x[0], x[1], x[2])
        B2 = self.my_3d_interp(x_, y_, z_, self.By, x[0], x[1], x[2])
        B3 = self.my_3d_interp(x_, y_, z_, self.Bz, x[0], x[1], x[2])
        # Results to matrices
        B = [B1, B2, B3];
        return B

B = Field(atPoint())
```

Comment: Question is not really clear, what is the expected output? Does `print(B)` work?

Comment: `print(B)` does not work because `B = Field(atPoint())` is wrong. My question is how to correct this command.

Comment: Added my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate your class first, then call the method:

```
B = Field().atPoint()
```

EDIT: You also need to pass the parameters B and D. Assuming the values:

```
B = Field(B=[1, 2, 3], D=[4, 5, 6]).atPoint()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got this error:     B = Field().atPoint()
  File "particle_in_field.py", line 64, in __init__
    self.Bx, self.By, self.Bz = kwargs.get('B')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable